# consul agent join - i/o timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, consul, terraform

I have 3 Consul Servers I have created within AWS. They were created with Terraform and are joined as part of a cluster.

There is a security group created as part of that Terraform which allowed inbound TCP/UDP on 8300, 8301, 8302, 8400, 8500.

I have installed the consul agent on a new Ubuntu 16.04 instance.

I collect the private IP of one of the Consul servers and try to join it from the client:

`consul agent -join 172.1.1.1:8301 -data-dir /tmp/consul`

Result:

```
==> Starting Consul agent...
==> Joining cluster...
==> 1 error(s) occurred:

* Failed to join 172.1.1.1: dial tcp 172.1.1.1:8301: i/o timeout
```

I can't see what is missing here that is stopping the client from joining.

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/about).

Comment: Ok, thank you for letting me know. If I can effectively "close" this question, I will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not enough data in the question. What do you mean you collected the private IP, was it the server's private IP assigned by the subnet, or is the IP you listed actually a "TaggedAddresses" from the consul itself, which is created if you are not running consul on the host network. So clearly, you need to share some of your consul server configuration too.

Secondly, if it the server's private IP only, please make sure that there is no issue in the NACL or ephemeral ports. You will find more information on the following link from amazon's official documentation:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html#VPC_ACLs_Ephemeral_Ports